# compare ctypes arrays without additional memory

Tags: python, ctypes

I have two large ctypes arrays which I would like to compare, without additional memory. Direct comparison doesn't work:

```
>>> a = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'1'*0x100000)
>>> b = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'1'*0x100000)
>>> a == b
False
```

Using either the `value` or `raw` attribute creates a copy of the array in memory.

Using `memoryview` to wrap both buffers slows things down by a lot.

For windows a possible solution is to use `msvcrt.memcmp` directly, but is there a more pythonic way or cross-platform way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specific C libraries can be found in a platform indpendent way using `ctypes.util.find_library`. The functions that the library exposes can be used as desired.

Thus arrays can be compared by doing the following:

```
libc_name = ctypes.util.find_library("c")
libc = ctypes.CDLL(libc_name)

libc.memcmp.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_size_t)

len(a) == len(b) and libc.memcmp(a, b, len(a)) == 0
```

Be warned, these function calls are very unforgiving if called incorrectly. By setting the argtypes of the function you make the function check its parameters before calling the library function.

A purely pythonic way to compare the arrays, without using large additional amounts of memory would be the following. It uses a generator, to compare each element at a time, rather than copying the entire arrays elsewhere and then comparing them.

```
len(a) == len(b) and all(x == y for x, y in zip(a,b))
```

The downside of this is that many objects, each with a small memory footprint, will be created -- which will come at its own computational expense (CPU rather than memory).

Comment: `ctypes.pythonapi.memcmp` doesn't exist for python 3.4.1 on windows 7. It probably wasn't exported.

Comment: I've added a more robust way to gain access to libc. Works on windows 8 and ubuntu 14.

Comment: You may also wish to look at the difference between `cdll` and `pydll`. `cdll` release the global interpreter lock whilst `pydll` does not. Meaning, another thread can execute simultaneously on another processor whilst a `cddl` function is executing.